# The meaning of "short of the cut-off"

Tags: meaning

I have heard this term a lot and in different places but I do want to know the exact meaning. Googling didn't reveal anything that I could understand the meaning.

Comment: context is vital here. "the cut off" could mean an exit on the highway, or a cut-off date in a schedule, or a limit to qualify for something. "short of" generally means before or not quite reaching. Why not edit a few examples into your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short of the cut-off* is not an idiom. It refers to coming in just under a desired grade or just behind a deadline.

A [*cut-off*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cutoff) point or level that is a designated limit of something, the time when something must be done or completed.

[Short](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/short): not extended in time.

> If your marks fall 3% short of the cut-off, our Admissions Office will automatically look at your ABS form and consider you for admission based on the information...
>
> While we try to be flexible if a child is just a few months **short of the cut off** for a program in an older age group, we need to respect the other children in our programs...

Comment: for *short*, I'd go with definition 5a (*not coming up to a measure or requirement*) in this case.

Comment: @Hellion - yes, that would be better perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

In accountancy *cut-off* is extensively used. It usually implies the timing of a month or year-end.

But it is usually advantageous to be 'short of the cut-off' rather than to run over the cut- off.

For example let's say the date for monthly sales 'cut-off' is midnight on 31st January. Any sale that takes place in the hours before cut-off can be included in the month's results. If they are 'past the cut-off' they can't.

So in business it is often better to be 'short of the cut-off'. Although this is not a term that is much used. One would normally say ;pre- or post-cut off, or before or after.